# Line f(0) = 0 closest to a set of points

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

Does anyone know a fast way to find a line closest to a set a points in python? (but the line should always cross the origin, in other words f(0) = 0)

Given the equation of the line y = mx + 0 I want to find the m that optimizes this distance to every point in the set.

[image]

The image above is an example, the line should be closest to all the points. I tried doing this using scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar but the performance was not good enough, I wonder if there is a faster algorithm or a analytical way of doing this.

Comment: @Padderby least squares will not do.

Comment: @Padserby The least square regression does not minimize the distances between the points and the line. It minimizes the difference between the sum of the square of the differences of the y coordinates of the data points and the y coordinates of the line.

Comment: @Passerby Read carefully the first answer in the link you provided.

Comment: I found https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html but the result line does not always crosses the origin.

Comment: @left_brain `numpy.linalg.lstsq` will give you a value of the parameter `m` for a line that crosses the origin. This line will minimize the sum of squares of distances to the given points.  I am not sure how you are getting a line that does not cross the origin without purposefully modifying the data.

Comment: @bb1 but numpy.linalg.lstsq returns a "m, c" parameters, the solution with the m and c parameters is different from the solution with the m parameter only. I want just the m.

Comment: `numpy.linalg.lstsq` returns a tuple of four values. The first one is the least square solution which is the value of `m`.  However, least squares will minimize the square of distances between the y-coordinates, If you really want to minimize distances of points to the line, you will need a different method.

Comment: Are your points always in the first quadrant?

Comment: @trincot always in the first and forth quadrant

Answer (score 0):

The distance formula can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line. You want to minimize the sum of the distances but the distance formula contains an absolute value which will created a discontinuity in the first derivative which will prevent numerical solvers from finding the solution. Alternatively you could minimize the square of the sum of the distances. However, it's not the same as minimizing the sum of the distances.

Comment: Is minimizing the square of the sum of the distances faster than minimizing the sum of the distances?

Comment: As stated minimizing sum of distances will not work. Minimizing sum of squares will and I bet an analytical solution can be found. Post in math stackexchange.